# Pycharm shows no autocompletion or documentation for methods

Tags: python, matplotlib, methods, autocomplete, pycharm

This is a simple case where I imported pyplot from matplotlib. Pycharm shows me the autocomplete list, definition, parameter information, and documentation for anything like subplots() in plt.subplots(), but it does not show anything of the above for any line with "ax" as the prefix, basically the methods.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(squares)

ax.set_title("Square Numbers", fontsize=24)
ax.set_xlabel("Value", fontsize=14)
ax.set_ylabel("Square of value", fontsize=14)

plt.show()
```

I have showing parameter information, quick definition and quick documentation on hover all enabled in the settings with minimal delay.

How can I solve this so Pycharm will show me an autocomplete list or a documentation as I type the methods? I'm still learning Python so such features are very useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE doesn't understand `subplots` return type. I created a ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-38100

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
ax: Axes
```

can be used as a workaround.